# Adding images to custom Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

Hello I just need to finish my  custom list view by adding an array of image along the left hand side. Currently I have added text which works perfectly fine just need to add images as well. I'm guess you set them up as an array similar to what I have already done for text but just need to see how its been done.

ListviewAdapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

String[] features={};
String[] clicks={};


Context c;
LayoutInflater inflater;




public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] features, String[] clicks) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row, features);

    this.c = context;
    this.features = features;
    this.clicks = clicks;





}

public class ViewHolder{

    TextView txtphone;
    TextView txtcall;


}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){


        inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
    }

    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();


    holder.txtphone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtphone);
    holder.txtcall= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtcall);


    holder.txtphone.setText(features[position]);
    holder.txtcall.setText(clicks[position]);


    return convertView;


}
}
```

---

Main Activity

```
String[] feature= {"Phone", "Email", "Website", "Opening Times"};
String[] click = {"click", "click", "click", "click", "click"};
int[] images ={R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery, R.drawable.ic_menu_send};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_us);



    contactUs = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactUsListView);




    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this,feature,click);
    contactUs.setAdapter(adapter);


    contactUs.setOnItemClickListener(new Itemlist());

}
```

---

As you can see I have added two images to the top of my main activity but just need a little advice to applying it to my listview

Comment: Have you google it for this.?

Comment: see this link. its help u..http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add `ImageView` to your `custom_row` layout. Let's say you've added it with id `imgView`. You should have the same amount of images as items in your `ListView`. Now you need to change code in adapter as follows

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

String[] features={};
String[] clicks={};
int[] images={};


Context c;
LayoutInflater inflater;




public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] features, String[] clicks, int[] images) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row, features);

    this.c = context;
    this.features = features;
    this.clicks = clicks;
    this.images = images;





}

public class ViewHolder{

    TextView txtphone;
    TextView txtcall;
    ImageView imgView;    

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){


        inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
    }

    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();


    holder.txtphone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtphone);
    holder.txtcall= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtcall);
    holder.imgView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);


    holder.txtphone.setText(features[position]);
    holder.txtcall.setText(clicks[position]);
    holder.imgView.setImageResource(images[position]);


    return convertView;


}
}
```

Make `images` the same size as `features` and `clicks`

```
int[] images ={R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery, R.drawable.ic_menu_send, R.drawable.ic_menu_send, R.drawable.ic_menu_send, R.drawable.ic_menu_send};
```

And initialize adapter as follows

```
   ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this,feature,click,images);
```